# Building a reusable framework with emscripten

Tags: emscripten

I have a somewhat beginner-ish question regarding emscripten. Most of the documentation I've found seems to be about building "programs" with it - things that can be run directly in the browser.

I'm interested in building something slightly different. I want to transpile an existing framework implemented in C, which exports a C API, as a library of javascript (and, presumably, WASM) that can be downloaded and invoked by other web applications.

What is the overall approach for doing something like this in emscripten? What flags and or options are necessary to express that the final target is a callable library, rather than a program?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what part of this is "too broad"? I'm asking exactly for how to target a library with emscripten, rather than a program. That doesn't seem broad *at all*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do for this is export the C API methods (using the `EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE` macro, for example) and call them from JS (using `ccall`, for example).

In general, a "normal" program with `main()` is exactly the same, except that `main()` is automatically exported for you, and automatically called. So there isn't a clear program/library distinction. (In fact, a program with `main()` can also export other C functions, and you can call those from JS.)

For details on `ccall` etc. see https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I managed to stumble to this conclusion too, and things are working for me now. I have some follow up questions about how "shared libraries" are supposed to work, but I'm not 100% clear if I need them, and I'll come back to that in another post.

Comment: One more comment - is there any material difference between `EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE` and manually tagging with `__attribute__((__used__))`?

Comment: Should be no difference between the two, the macro is defined that way in fact, https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/system/include/emscripten/emscripten.h#L58